# Парсинг XML в dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

Сейчас переписываю хранимку на динамик SQL, и вот с чем столкнулся:
(оригинальный код:)

```
AND (m.clientId IN (
                        SELECT Tbl.Col.value('clientId[1]', 'varchar(7)') as clientId 
                        FROM @clientXml.nodes('Clients/Client') Tbl(Col)
                        )  
                        OR @clientXml IS NULL)
```

> @clientXml

имеет тип xml, и я не могу его правильно передать в сам текст запроса. например, я так пробую:

```
(m.clientId IN (
    SELECT Tbl.Col.value(''clientId[1]'', ''varchar(7)'') as clientId 
    FROM ',  @clientXml,'.nodes(''Clients/Client'') ',  ' Tbl(Col)   )');
```

Но не работает.

Как правильно передать в динамический SQL параметр с типом  XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ 1**

Вы можете воспользоваться системной процедурой [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188001.aspx), в качестве параметров передаются текст запроса, список параметров с типами и сами параметры:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<Data/>'

declare @dynSql nvarchar(max);
set @dynSql = N'select @xml.query(''.'')'

exec sp_executesql @dynSql, N'@xml xml', @xml
```

Или (если вы хотите использовать разные имена для формального и действительного параметров):

```
declare @xmlActual xml
set @xmlActual = '<Data/>'

declare @dynSql nvarchar(max);
set @dynSql = N'select @xmlFormal.query(''.'')'

exec sp_executesql @dynSql, N'@xmlFormal xml', @xmlFormal = @xmlActual
```

**Способ 2**

Передать через временную таблицу:

```
declare @xmlActual xml
set @xmlActual = '<Data/>'

create table #params (xmlParam xml)
insert into #params values (@xmlActual)

exec('
declare @xmlFormal xml
select @xmlFormal = xmlParam from #params
select @xmlFormal.query(''.'')
')
```

Comment: Я использовал первый способ. Спасибо.